# Code Snippets plugin by Shea

Tags: plugins

I just downloaded Code Snippets for my Wordpress website that looks really promising for a newbie like me.  I'm getting ready to create some snippets and I'm concerned about any potential errors causing my site to shut down (I just had that happen yesterday when I tried to enter snippets in my Highend Child theme.  I needed to be rescued by my webhost customer service).

I see in the [FAQ on this page](https://wordpress.org/plugins/code-snippets/#description), a person asked about this potential.  Shea said it's possible to activate safe mode by adding the following line to your `wp-config.php` file, just before the line that reads `/* That's all, stop editing! Happy blogging. */`:

```
define('CODE_SNIPPETS_SAFE_MODE', true);
```

Trouble is I can't find where wp-config.php file is.  I did find under Appearance-Edit Themes-Theme files there is a plain config.php file but I couldn't find the line that reads as above to know where to safely put this line.

Just trying to play it safe before I start creating code snippets and possibly break my site!

Thanks

Comment: In `wp-config.php`, which is in the root *(where wordpress lives)* or sometimes a folder higher *(when wordpress is in a subfolder)*, you should look for a line which start with `if ( !defined(ANSPATH') ) define('ABSPATH,`  and so on. Just add it above that and you should be fine.

Comment: You'll need either FTP access or file manager access to get to `wp-config.php`. You can't edit it through `wp-admin`. While you are at it, it would be safer to disable theme and plugin file editing through wp-admin, because they present a big security risk - and a higher risk of breaking your site than if you SFTP the files safely.

Comment: Thx for help Charles and WebElaine.  WebElaine, if by file manager access you mean that I'm an administrator/user then I guess I can get to wp-config.php. I temporarily have FTP, one more day left of 7-day trial of "Transmit".  I'm not sure if I'm going to purchase yet, still trying to figure out how to use it.  Charles, I can't find the line that begins as you desciribe~

Comment: update, found the line location.  Now I'm not sure I should jump to "safe mode".  WebElaine, how do I disable theme and plugin file editing through wp-admin?  sorry for such basic questions.

Comment: @sammy: If you would prefer not to edit your wp-config.php file, you can also enable safe mode by adding `&snippets-safe-mode=1` to a WordPress URL. So if the URL was `https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=snippets`, you could enable safe mode by visiting `https://example.com/wp-admin/admin.php?page=snippets&snippets-safe-mode=1`